# How can I get the bounds of a Visual relative to another visual's coordinate system?

Tags: wpf, interface, coordinate-transformation

While implementing `IScrollInfo`'s `MakeVisible` member, I ran into an issue.  I need to get the coordinates of that `Visual`'s bounds relative to the panel which is being scrolled.

Now if this were a `UIElement`, this would be easy as I'd just call its 'TranslatePoint' method, but `UIElement` is a subclass of `Visual`, not the other way around, so I can't necessarily count on that.

How would one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual provides the [TransformToVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual.aspx) method, which returns a [GeneralTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.generaltransform.aspx) that can be used to transform points or rectangles:

```
var transform = visual1.TransformToVisual(visual2);
var point = transform.Transform(new Point(...));
```

If `visual1` is a ContainerVisual, you can do this:

```
var bounds = transform.TransformBounds(visual1.ContentBounds);
```

or

```
var bounds = transform.TransformBounds(visual1.DescendantBounds);
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!  I used the TransformBounds directly with the rectangle passed in to the IScrollInfo.MakeVisible call, and that worked great!